# How is it possible to install MintMenu in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, menu, mate

I know that there were some PPA's for older Ubuntu versions (11.04 and previous ones),when Gnome 2 was the default desktop environment.
Now, I have installed the MATE D.E. on Ubuntu 12.04, but it does not contain the MintMenu. So how can I install it WITHOUT adding the Linux Mint repositories to the software sources?

Comment: Consider this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository .  It's the same basic idea except that Debian is generally upstream and Mint is generally downstream.  All the disadvantages still apply.  It is not recommended to do this, and has potential to break a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

you can download the MintMenu package [here](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mintmenu/mintmenu_5.3.5_all.deb). You can browse the Linux Mint 13 [repository](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Maya) if the MintMenu package requires any dependencies.

Comment: Link is broken.