# How do I install Backtrack applications in Ubuntu?

Tags: backtrack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Debian Sid as Package Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository)

i was just trying to download and install backtrack application but in it's offical site it had the options only for Gnome and KDE, but not unity, does it mean backtrack won't work on unity? or if i can install it on unity, how can i do it after i download it's package from the official website? i am going to download:

> BackTrack 5 R3 Gnome 32bit

Comment: It's the same as [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository). The answer is, **don't do it, you'll end up in pain**. Maintain Backtrack on its own USB stick or in a VM. Trying to get it on Ubuntu right now is very, very difficult and painful, so don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the options already cited:

1) Just use Backtrack in a VM - easiest, but some of the packages are relatively broken as of now and some of the packages are way out of date

2) Compile everything from source - Yes, really.  This is easier than troubleshooting all the SNAFUs from adding the BT repositories.

3) Debianize everything properly to build against current Ubuntu - constant work in progress and not a lot of community around it.

4) Add the Backtrack repositories - worst option.  Seems like the best option out of the gate, but you WILL have problems and lots of them.

Answer (score 3):

#### Moderator note:

This question is more or less an exact duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository), and as such you need to be extremely careful with how you do things. It is **not** recommend to do this. For more reasoning, see the question linked to above.

Although this might be off topic but I wont care about that as the question is too straightforward and simple.

**Short answer:** *YES, You Can.*

**Long answer:** You can add backtrack repository in your source file and install whatever software you want. here is the repository.

```
deb http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution main microverse non-free testing
deb http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution main microverse non-free testing
deb http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution main microverse non-free testing
```

append those lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and run

```
wget http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/backtrack.gpg -O – | sudo apt-key add -
```

to add backtrack gpg key, then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install any software from backtrack repo.