# More up to date vim repo

Tags: vim

The vim I currently have installed is version 7.3.547, however I need at least version 7.3.584. I cannot find a repo for a more up to date version.

Does one exist or must I build vim myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on [the Debian site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository) for vim with parameters 'Distribution = any' and 'Version = main', you will see that there's a package: `vim (2:7.3.923-1 and others)`. It's in the software distribution called `sid` - the 'unstable' version, containing initially uploaded packages.

So you can add `sid` to your repository sources.

But... that is a **bad idea**. Why? See this [post on Askubuntu.com about adding Debian Sid as a package repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository).

Comment: Unfortunately I need a newer version of vim for the YMC plugin to work. If it's such a bad idea to add the repo I'll just manually build it.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a [vim-snapshots PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nmi/+archive/vim-snapshots) was created for this. To install it, I used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nmi/vim-snapshots
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```