# wedge with apt-get

Tags: apt, dependencies

I get the following error message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fuse-utils : Depends: libfuse2 (= 2.8.4-1.3) but 2.9.2-4 is installed
 gvfs : Depends: gvfs-daemons (>= 1.16.2-2) but it is not installed
        Depends: gvfs-daemons (< 1.16.2-2.1~) but it is not installed
        Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.16.2-2) but it is not installed
 gvfs-backends : Depends: gvfs (= 1.6.1-0ubuntu1build1) but 1.16.2-2 is installed
 libfuse-dev : Depends: libfuse2 (= 2.8.4-1.3) but 2.9.2-4 is installed
 python-apt : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-13 is installed
```

I haven't got a clue how to proceed.  Simply removing these packages creates a cascade of pain.

This was marked as a duplicate.  I'm pretty sure I tried all of those suggestions.  Making forward progress seems to require identifying what package to remove.   Removing gvfs,
gvfs-backends, libfuse-dev, python-apt all lead to cascading problems.

1. Under Ubuntu Software tab, enable all the repositories. -- this is a headless server, there is no GUI
2. `sudo apt-get clean`  -- doesn't help
3. `sudo apt-get -f install`  -- doesn't help
4. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
   Then run this again:

   `sudo apt-get -f install`

   doesn't help
5. `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade`  -- doesn't help
6. `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade`

   `--- E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`
7. Disabling a PPA means no more updates for the packages installed from that PPA. To disable a PPA: Open Software Center > Edit > Software Sources Or,

   -- again headless server, no gui
8. `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`  -- won't run because of existing errors

I'm looking for new suggestions.  The standard one's aren't working.

My [/etc/apt/sources.list](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5706553/).

Comment: visit : http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Can you upload your /etc/apt/sources.list as well as all the '*.list' files inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to http://paste.ubuntu.com and include the links in your question?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5706553/

Answer (score 1):

This is in your sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ experimental main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ experimental main
```

You added a Debian repository to Ubuntu. Probably you broke your system very badly.

[Adding Debian Sid as Package Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/116257/65926)

You could try removing those lines, then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Also, if aptitude is installed, run `sudo aptitude` and look under "Obsolete and Locally Created Packages". Write down these "obsolete" (packages that doesn't exist in repos) and run:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall <list of packages>
```

That list of packages can also be found in synaptic, clicking the "Origin" button then selecting "Local".

But I really think you'll have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which i solved by downgrading libfuse so it matched the version libfuse-dev required.  For this question it would be:

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse2=2.8.4-1.3
```

after that fuse-utils and libfuse-dev should install OK.

the gvfs and python problems are probably to do with using mixed debian and ubuntu repositories - but specifying a version might force apt to get it from the correct repo, which might solve the problem.