# Need to install a package from Debian repos in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm working in Ubuntu Bionic Docker image and am in need of the [libcxx-serial-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libcxx-serial-dev) package, but this only seems to be available in the Debian repos. How do I go about installing this package on Ubuntu 18.04?

I tried adding the following to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian main

but then I couldn't find the public key for the repo.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Debian Sid as Package Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository)

Comment: It might, but apt throws me an error because I haven't added the public key of the repo, and I don't know how or where to get said pub key.

Comment: Don't do it! Mixing repositories of two different distributions may make your system files incompatible and your computer may not work.

Comment: Do not invent bicycles, use https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libcxx-serial-dev on focal docker image.

Comment: Yes thank you, see my answer down, this is exactly what I resorted to.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libcxx-serial-dev/download instead

or use source package from main repository
https://gitlab.com/leamas/cxx-serial and build it for your ubuntu

the build process is described in the ReadMe file of the official repository

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this package just isn't available in the Bionic Beaver repos, but it is however in the Focal Fossa repos. Updating my Docker image to `ubuntu:focal` solved my issue.