# How to install Debian package in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, debian

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, and I've been having issues with my wifi for a while now (even before I upgraded, as a matter of fact). Looking around, I suspect it's a driver issue. The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't package the drivers I need.

[I found the drivers in Debian Bookworm](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/firmware-realtek) (which is what Ubuntu 22.04 is based on), but I don't know how to install it from there, as it looks like it assumes that it's managed by apt. I'd like to add it to my sources.list, but I don't know how to do that on Ubuntu with a Debian package (putting aside all the [useless answers I found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116257/adding-debian-sid-as-package-repository) telling me what a bad idea that was).

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add Debian repositories to Ubuntu. You can install a Debian package manually, by first downloading it:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-realtek_20210818-1_all.deb
```

And then installing it:

```
sudo apt install ./firmware-realtek_20210818-1_all.deb
```

However, this is a manual procedure, and you have to update it manually by following the same procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If both use apt and I'm not employing this universally, why is this less advisable than using a PPA?

Comment: There is difference between adding a PPA and adding a Debian repo. The last can result in versioning conflicts, demolishing your system. WIth this method, you're in charge of installing the "rogue" package, and thus responsible for any potential versioning conflicts yourself. However, this particular packages shouldn't give any conflicts, but other packages might.

Comment: Is there a way to add a Debian repo for a single package then, or will it automatically include a bunch of other things that I don't want to?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to add repo for a single package - that's not how it works.

Comment: @Yehuda "*add a Debian repo*" seems like such a tame term. But the version number suggests that you want to add *debian sid* to your Ubuntu system. Think about that for a minute. If you don't find anything wrong with the concept, then look up the [purpose of the sid repo](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/) and pay close attention to the risks.