# Enable compiz option without replacing the gnome-shell window manager

Tags: gnome, compiz, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I have Ubuntu 14.10 and `compiz` version `0.9.12`.

I want to enable some compiz effects (Wobbly Windows, Opacity, etc.) but when I run the command: `compiz --replace` It removes my wallpaper, workspaces, keyboard shortcuts, gnome dash, etc. And enable the compiz options, after restart, everything come back but compiz options disappear.

Anyone know why this occurs? I appreciate your help.

EDIT:
I found some useful information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411147/what-is-the-relationship-between-unity-gnome-gnome-3-compiz-metacity-and-li/411160#411160) and also found the definition of that command (`compiz --replace`): **"Replace any existing window managers"**.

Long story short:
I select some options in CCSM, then execute `compiz --replace`, and happen what I said, the execute `gnome-shell --replace` and come back wallpaper, dash, keyboard shortcuts, etc. but compiz options disappear.

Question:
How can I turn on some compiz option without replacing the window manager, using gnome-shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only run one or the other.