# Difference Between Ubuntu and Ubuntu-Gnome

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, derivatives

Hai all I just want to know is there any Difference Between [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) and [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/). I love to use Ubuntu... But I hate the Unity desktop... So want an Ubuntu system with GNOME 3. So if I install Ubuntu GNOME is that same as that of a usual Ubuntu with the GNOME desktop installed?

I just want to know, does this mean if I install Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.2 then everything other than the desktop is same as in Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Unity and GNOME](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333237/difference-between-unity-and-gnome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. It's the same OS, but looking other.

Also, if you want to have GNOME (or other desktop environment - there are lots of them!) without installing system again **it is possible** and pretty easy. To see what desktop environments are available and how to install them you can head to [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) .

Comment: So if I installed ubuntugnome it will install the same os.  No difference with ubuntu 14.04 yes?  The bugs and fixes all are same..??   Only change is unity will be replaced with ubuntu.. Yes na?  Than you for your comment.. :)

Comment: @Nithin.P Yes. It's only different "skin" for your system. Also, if answer satisfies You, could You please mark it as correct answer? :)

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to install the version of Ubuntu with your preferred desktop environment as the default. If you install plain Ubuntu, add the package for Gnome (or any other desktop), then delete Unity, it will lead to quirky problems with your interface. So the difference between Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome (assuming you want Gnome as your desktop environment) is that installing Ubuntu Gnome flavor is saving you a whole bunch of hassles.