# What's the difference between Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10?

Tags: 16.04, dell, 16.10

I've heard about Ubuntu 16.04 but I've also heard of Ubuntu 16.10. What's the difference between these two?

Will either of them be compatible with a Dell Optiplex 755 usff?

Also, I've heard about LTS (Long-term support) and I don't know whether it means its out of support or in support.

Comment: Do a bit more 2017 research before installing 16.10, which is already EOL and out of support.

Comment: Don't take our word on compatibility. Create a LiveUSB (search for it) and safely find out yourself. Then you will know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical, the UK-based company behind the Ubuntu flavor of Linux, releases new versions of the OS twice a year, once in April (the .04) and once in October (the .10), every year. Being November 2017, the most recent version is currently 17.10.

Because of the 6-month window between releases there usually isn't dramatic changes in versions that close together -- you won't notice much difference between 16.04 and 16.10.

It should be compatible with your machine but the official requirements are:

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- 2 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

What you should be asking about is the differences with 17.10, which is radically different than 16.04. After a Hacker News thread overwhelmingly suggested Canonical abandon its own custom desktop, Unity, in favor of the more standard Linux desktop, Gnome, ([see this thread to understand the difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333237/difference-between-unity-and-gnome)), Canonical finally went ahead and made the switch in 17.10.

My personal opinion: if it ain't broke, don't try to break it by upgrading. Unless you're a power user who can debug boot errors it's probably not worth the hassle, unless you just really love Gnome and despise Unity.

Comment: Even though Mr Shuttleworth is indeed a South African, Canonical themselves are UK based, with their HQ in Loondoon. I know, odd. but such is life.

Comment: Updated.  My mistake.

Comment: Hey @OrdinaryHuman , a very easy mistake to make. Who would know a South African names OS, set up by a South African would be..... English !

Comment: Yeah now I understand