# What is the difference between two desktop installation command?

Tags: server, 18.04, unity, gnome, desktop-environments

These days, I installed desktop environment on Ubuntu 18.04 server LTS that is based on Gnome,

Firstly, I use command to install desktop

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

when it was finished and reboot, it was strange that machine stops at booting step.
Checking the command information, I found that GDM3 cannot be reloaded correctly. So I switch to lightdm and reboot it: problem fixed.
The session information will be like:
[image]

Another way.i use another command to install desktop

`sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`

the process of installation is success and smooth with no errors.
check the session like it:
[image]

*So, I wonder ask u about the relationship between ubuntu.desktop and unity.desktop, though some answers can be searched but not clearly.*

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: I think it's related but not an exact duplicate.

Comment: They may be two similar questions ,but are not exactly the same

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I think [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/526867/225694) to the called duplicate does a good job of explaining the relationship between the 2 packages installed by the commands you mention. You can obtain a great deal of information about specific packages and their content via https://packages.ubuntu.com/ Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for all，your answer are really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-desktop) and [`ubuntu-unity-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-unity-desktop) are both [meta packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package?noredirect=1&lq=1) to install a graphical desktop environment and its dependencies.

`ubuntu-desktop` installs the default Desktop of Ubuntu which is *Gnome3* since Ubuntu 17.10. From 11.04 to 17.04, the default Desktop was *Unity*.

Since 17.10 the [prior `ubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop) meta-package providing Unity is named [`ubuntu-unity-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-unity-desktop), which is as the name says a meta-package providing the *Unity* Desktop.

Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333237/difference-between-unity-and-gnome) to learn about the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it may be give me some answer and inspiration in a way. But i wonder know the difference between two commands and also the compatibility between GDM3 and ubuntu.desktop when using command `apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @mingwenzang I don't see those elements in your original question. This seems like an excellent answer to the question that you actually asked.