# What is the meaning of exp9ubuntu1 suffix in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, versions

Here is my clang version:
Ubuntu clang version 3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)
And what I don't know is the **meaning** of "**exp9ubuntu1**"?
Please Help, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you break this down:

1. The `3.2` is the upstream version of clang that you are using and which the packages is based.
2. The `-1` is the Debian versioning which the package was Debianized. Most packages that aren't Debianized upstream has this `-#` suffix.
3. `~exp9` means Experimental build, 9 version. In this case Ubuntu imported clang from the Debian experimental branch. Those packages normally has this suffix since some patches were introduced while they were in the experimental branch that weren't applied upstream or that were cherry picked from upstream.
4. `ubuntu1` means that the package was modified to be Ubuntu complaint, that cannot be applied upstream, or that hasn't been applied upstream.

You can see that the versions in the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/c/clang/clang_3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1/changelog) has a value that says the branch that applied the fixes:

> clang (3.2-1~exp9**ubuntu1**) **raring**; urgency=low
>
> - Merge with Debian; remaining changes:
>
>   - Do not build-depend on binutils-gold.
>   - Don't bump the epoch for raring.
>
>   -- Matthias Klose   Thu, 18 Apr 2013 17:17:28 +0200
>
> clang (1:3.2-1~**exp9**) **experimental**; urgency=low
>
> [ Peter Michael Green ]
>
> - Use binutils-gold only on architectures where it is actually available
> - 33-armhf-defaults.diff Fix defaults to use correct CPU and FPU for
>     debian  armhf (Closes: #704111)
> - 34-powerpc-no-altivec.diff disable altivec by default on powerpc because
>     debian powerpc does not require altivec (patch **cherry picked from ubuntu**)
>
>   -- Sylvestre Ledru   Tue, 02 Apr 2013 19:37:22
>     +0200

Comment: "ubuntu2" means the package was modified **twice**to be Ubuntu complaint. Do I understand it right? Thanks.

Comment: @sakuya only if this *"twice"* were consecutive and only in Ubuntu. Check the changelog and you will see a entry for `3.2-1~exp5ubuntu2`. It means that between each release there wasn't modification from upstream but only in Ubuntu.

Comment: for Ubuntu, is "upstream" means Debian? Sorry, I don't understand "upstream". Thanks.

Comment: @sakuya check this question http://askubuntu.com/q/4868/169736